# JavaScript Post Message Cross Domain - Send Data from different functions to different output fields

Tags: javascript

i'm currently developing a little tool for a cultural institution, using JavaScript and HTML. But as i am a starter in Java, i got stuck on this problem:

I have two HTML documents, which communicate via cross-domain messaging. The idea is, that one document is the backend and one is the frontend. What should be done is filling in numbers in different text fields in Backend (1 - 5) and send them to matching fields in frontend. Frontend will be a window on a second screen at some point.

I've set up everything so far, communication works basically, but i just can't get button 1 send the value only to result field 1, button 2 to result field 2 and so forth ...

Function for sending is postMessage(), function for receiving is onMessage().

How do define from which function in parent window the message came to have it displayed in a matching place in child window?

Here is my code. I have 5 different input fields, where inserted numbers should be transferred to child window to 5 different output fields.

```html
var childWindowUrl = "secondwindow.html";

 function newWindow() {
  
  var win = window.open(childWindowUrl, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
  childWindows.push(win);
 }

 function broadcast() {
 var amountBox = document.querySelector("#amount");
 balance = parseFloat(amountBox.value);
 for (var i = 0; i < childWindows.length; i++) {
 childWindows[i].postMessage(balance, "*");
 }
  
  // Input field
  
  <input type="text" id ="amount" />
  
  // HTML Buttons
  
  <button onclick="broadcast()">Send balance</button>
  <button onclick="newWindow()">New Window</button>
  
  // Child Window Code
 
 function onMessage(e) {
if (e.origin !== 'parentwindow.html') {
 document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = e.data;
 }
 }

window.addEventListener('message', onMessage, true);
```

Comment: Anybody? I reckon this is really easy, but i'm really kind a stuck here ...

Comment: can you post some code (*the button html and the attached handlers*)

Answer (score 1):

No information about the source function is provided, by default, when you use `postMessage`. No information about the destination is provided (other than the targetOrigin) either.

You need to encode the information yourself.

e.g.

```
targetWindow.postMessage({ button: 1, says: "Hello, world" }, "http://example.com",);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody! In the end i had a friend help me out.

This is how:

```html
Java Script:

      function broadcast() {
     var amountBox = document.querySelector("#amount");
     var message = {"position": 1, "balance": parseFloat(amountBox.value)};
     for (var i = 0; i < childWindows.length; i++) {
      childWindows[i].postMessage(message, "*");
     }
    }

AND in second window

function onMessage(e) {
 if (e.origin !== 'parentwindow.html'){
  document.getElementById('balance' + e.data.position).innerHTML = e.data.balance;
 }
}

window.addEventListener('message', onMessage, true);
```